# dropdown menu with submenu and texture?

Tags: html, css

So i never created a drop down menu before.

my question is how can i a texture for my navigation menu?

i have the html code:

```
<div id="nav">

 <ul class="bar">
 <li></li> 
 <li></li> 
 <li></li>     
 <li>Guitars</li> 
 <ul>
 <li>Fender</li>    
 <li>Yamaha</li> 
 </ul> 
 </ul>

</div>
```

So i want to add  a texture to all the navigation menu and submenus how can i do that?
can i use `background-image:('images/texture.png');` ?
I have a transparent image  and how can  i make the navigation menu horizontal?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I guess it's just a typo, but use `<ul class="bar">` instead of `<ul class"bar">`

Comment: haha my keyboard its too old! thanks for see the error.

Answer (score 1):

For the background image, use `url()` ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri)):

```
background-image: url('images/texture.png');
```

...but I don't see the point if the image is transparent.

To make the menu horizontal, use floating or inline-block elements:

```
.bar > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

or

```
.bar {
    overflow: auto; /* Different than visible, to clear floating */
}
.bar > li {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Just to supplement this answer, depending on where you'd like the texture to be applied you could apply this to the containing `div` or the `ul` element itself...

Comment: ok i will try thank you. but now i'm confused i never used >  between the class name and the li element.

Comment: @Fredericofrg `ul > li` means *all li elements which are **children** of an ul element*, and `ul li` means *all li elements which are **descendants** of an ul element*. The children selector is faster

Comment: @Fredericofrg The greater than symbol is used to select the immediate children of a specified element. See here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on what you want the texture on?

If you just want your submenu to have the texture

It would be something like

```
 ul.bar li ul {background-image: url('images/texture.png');}
```

You could also drop the background-image to background and add your repeats or center or top or whatever in the short version

```
 ul.bar li ul {background: url('images/texture.png') repeat center top;}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: its just a noise, i was confused if was better do  my navigation size on photoshop and put a black background color and apply a noise and put that big image on my website or just do a div and all the ul li elements  and put background-color black and apply background image with the noise.

Comment: Are you asking if you can use it more than once? In that case yes you can use it more than once without any performance issues because it will be come cached in the browser. add your noise everywhere!